# How to write a script for changing settings in a certain program

Tags: python, windows, internet-explorer

**Context for this question:**

My work uses an old system for accessing documents that we've published.  It is accessed through a web browser, but the thing is, it only works in internet explorer.  The issue everyone has is, once you find the document you want to open and open it, IE always prompts you with this message: "This page is accessing information that is not under its control.  This poses a security risk.  Do you want to continue?"
Everyone has just accepted it as an extra step you have to take every time you open one of these documents.  But recently someone found that you can fix that by changing IE's settings (Tools->Internet options->Security tab->Local intranet->Custom level->Change "Access data sources across domains" from Prompt to Enable).  This turns out to be a temporary fix though, because our settings are periodically overwritten by IT, back to where it was.

**The actual question:**

Is there some way to write a script in Python that can access and change the settings in Internet Explorer?  I'd like to write a script that is run periodically to make sure that setting is changed to "Enable" so that the dozens of people who use this file access system don't have to constantly be clicking through pop up messages for every document they open.  I have a basic knowledge of python, but don't know if there is a module or some method for changing a programs settings.  If there is another more appropriate alternative to Python, let me know about that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The settings in IE can also be edited through registry. The setting you want to edit is controlled by [this registry](https://admx.help/?Category=InternetExplorer&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.InternetExplorer::IZ_PolicyAccessDataSourcesAcrossDomains_3). So we can make a file to edit this registry to edit the IE setting.

The most convenient way to edit the registry is using a `.reg` file. You can try the steps below:

1. Create a new file and change the file extension to `.reg`.
2. Right click the `.reg` file and choose **Edit**.
3. Copy and paste the following code into the `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1]

"1406"=dword:00000000
```

4. Save the `.reg` file and double click it to run the code.

After running the file, you can check the setting in IE and you'll find it has been changed. You can run the file any time later you want to change the setting.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this on Monday and see if I get it to work.

Comment: Hi @chen Is there any update about the issue? May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer?